# Dynamic filepath & filename for FileHandler in logger config file in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a python log config file with a filehandler of the below form.

```
[handler_filelog]
class: FileHandler
args = ('/var/tmp/log/client.log','a')
```

Instead, I need it in the below form (dynamically generated path).

```
[handler_filelog]
class: FileHandler
args = ('/var/tmp/log_<unique_string>/client.log','a')
```

Multiple instances of the program may be running and hence non-conflicting log paths and files are to be used.
The logger once setup need not change till end of program execution.

Is there a way to handle this using the config file approach?
I am not keen on resorting to creating the loggers/handlers/formatters by myself since my log config file has many of these and config file based approach is much nicer.

(Update: I am using python 2.4)

Comment: Have you tried extending the FileHandler class?

Comment: Yes. As commented below it works if I instantiate the handler myself. To do the same via config file, I haven't figured out how to make the definition of my class visible to logging module.

Comment: Were you able to test the updated code posted in the answer? It worked for me with the old config format. So you don't need a dictionary based config file to get it to run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does what you need. You should first extend the FileHandler class. Place this in a file, say myHandler.py in your config file's directory:

```
import logging
import random
import os
class myFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self,path,fileName,mode):
        r = random.randint(1,100000)
        path = path+"/log_"+str(r)
        os.mkdir(path)
        super(myFileHandler,self).__init__(path+"/"+fileName,mode)
```

And then in the config file, you can use this custom FileHandler like this

```
class: myHandler.myFileHandler
args = ('/var/tmp','client.log','a')
```

I tested this one on my machine

Comment: With extending of FileHandler, I was able to get the behavior by creating my own handler and adding to the logger. But could not get this to work via the config file. The "randomFileHandler" is not defined at the point where logging module is using config ini. Am checking if there is a easy way to make the class definition visible or if I end up going the way of own handlers.

Comment: I attempted to make the definition visible by defining _logging.<myhandler> = <myhandler>_, but I run into the problem of _AttributeError: MyFileHandler instance has no attribute 'level'_ -> possibly http://bugs.python.org/issue8165. I am still checking if it is my incorrect usage or a known bug of logging module.

Comment: I am new to python inheritance. So, I was doing something terrible with the subclass initially. Looks like it works now though...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a different requirement -- to get the name of the file to which the logger was logging to. Just added a method to the class as suggested by you and it works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: how can i use in your answer os.environ passed to the args attribute?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Python 2.7 or 3.2, you can use [dictionary-based configuration](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig), which allows you to specify arbitrary callables to return handlers - you could e.g. use the process PID to construct the file name.

**Update:** If you are using 2.4, you can use the [logutils](http://code.google.com/p/logutils/) package, which should work with Python 2.4 (apart from the LoggerAdapter class, which requires 2.5 or later). The `logutils` package contains the dictionary-based configuration functionality.

Comment: I am using python 2.4. Thanks for the hint though, if the alternatives are not simple enough, I will probably remove config file and implement a dictionary based configuration myself. As of now this path is not yet desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the update pointing to logutils. This is a useful hint. This does address the question but I picked the other answer since it is more suitable for my needs (does not introduce new library dependency).

Comment: This answer should get more up-vote. Sorry for the op that s/he has to use Python2.4 but logging.config.dictConfig is the current standard where you can easily manipulate the config.

Answer (score 2):

"CallbackFilter" can be used to implement Dynamic filepath & filename for in logger config file in python. You can define write_dynamic_log as below:

```
def write_dynamic_log(record):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    dynamic_log_name = '/var/log/test_%s.log' %now
    log_file = open(dynamic_log_name, "w")
    log_file.write(record.msg)
    log_file.close();
    return True
```

Then in the config file, you can use this filter like this:

```
[handler_filelog]
class: FileHandler
formatter: brief
level   : INFO
filters: [write_dynamic_log]
filename: static.log
```

The INFO or above log will be output to static.log and also to dynamic_log.

I tested it in my django project, in which I wrote config in my settings.py. It works fine. LOGGING will is like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s - %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d\n%(message)s'
        },
        'debug': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s - %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d\n\033[34m%(message)s\033[0m'
        },
        'error': {
            'format': 'Component: %(module)s\nErrorCode: %(funcName)s\nReason: %(funcName)s\nDetail: [%(message)s]'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'write_error_logs': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': write_error_log,
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'debug': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug',
        },
        'error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/SmartStorageApp.err',
            'formatter': 'error',
            'filters': ['write_error_logs'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['debug' if DEBUG else 'console', 'error'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```