# Dynamic log filename based on logged in username

Tags: django

I would like to maintain independent user logs in django based on logged in username. Any assistance on configuring django logging callback filter will be appreciated

I followed instructions from this link but could not get it to work
[Dynamic filepath & filename for FileHandler in logger config file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405890/dynamic-filepath-filename-for-filehandler-in-logger-config-file-in-python/9408509)

```
def write_dynamic_log(record):



def write_dynamic_log(record):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    dynamic_log_name = '/var/logs/django/test_%s.log' %now
    log_file = open(dynamic_log_name, "a")
    log_file.write(record.msg)
    log_file.close();
    return True

'write_error_logs': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': write_dynamic_log,
        },
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow, can you please expand as `could not get it to work` what do you mean? Is there an error?

Comment: I was not able to pass the logged in username to function write_dynamic_log(record): 

The objective is to generate logs without modifying existing logging code
I wanted to modify the logging handlers to automatically set the username as filename.log