# Dynamically switching log storage folder

Tags: python, logging, handler

I am using Python's logging to log execution of functions and other actions within an application. The log files are stored in a remote folder, which is accessible automatically when I connect to VPN (let's say \remote\directory). That is normal situation, 99% of the time there is a connection and log is stored without errors.

I need a solution for a situation when either the VPN connection or Internet connection is lost and the logs are temporarily stored locally. I think that on each time something is attempted to be logged, I need to run a check if the remote folder is accessible. I couldn't really find a solution, but I guess I need to modify the FileHandler somehow.

TLDR: You can already scroll down to blues' answer and my UPDATE section - there is my latest attempt to solve the issue.

Currently my handler is set like this:

```
log = logging.getLogger('general')
handler_error = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_path+"\\error.log", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
log.addHandler(handler_error)
```

Here is a condition that sets the log path but only once - when logging is initialized. If I think correctly, I would like to run this condition each time the

```
if (os.path.isdir(f"\\\\remote\\folder\\")):  # if remote is accessible
    log_path = f"\\\\remote\\folder\\dev\\{d.year}\\{month}\\"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_path), exist_ok=True)  # create this month dir if it does not exist, logging does not handle that

else:  # if remote is not accesssible
    log_path = f"localFiles\\logs\\dev\\{d.year}\\{month}\\"
    log.debug("Cannot access the remote directory. Are you connected to the internet and the VPN?")
```

I have found a related thread, but was not able to adjust it to my own needs: [Dynamic filepath & filename for FileHandler in logger config file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405890/dynamic-filepath-filename-for-filehandler-in-logger-config-file-in-python/9408509)

Should I dig deeper into custom Handler or is there some other way? Would be enough if I could call my own function that changed the logging path if needed (or change logger to one with a proper path) when logging is being executed.

**UPDATE:**
Per blues's answer, I have tried modifying a handler to suit my needs. Unfortunately, the code below, in which I try to switch *baseFilename* between local and remote paths, does not work. The logger always saves the log to local log file (that has been set while initializing logger). Thus, I think that my attempts to modify the *baseFilename* do not work?

```
class HandlerCheckBefore(RotatingFileHandler):
    print("handler starts")
    def emit(self, record):

        calltime = date.today()

        if os.path.isdir(f"\\\\remote\\Path\\"):  # if remote is accessible

            print("handler remote")
            # create remote folders if not yet existent

            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(f"\\\\remote\\Path\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\"), exist_ok=True)
            if (self.level >= 20): # if error or above
                self.baseFilename = f"\\\\remote\\Path\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\error.log"
            else:
                self.baseFilename = f"\\\\remote\\Path\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\{calltime.strftime('%d')}-{calltime.strftime('%m')}.log"
            super().emit(record)

        else:  # save to local
            print("handler local")
            if (self.level >= 20): # error or above
                self.baseFilename = f"localFiles\\logs\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\error.log"
            else:
                self.baseFilename = f"localFiles\\logs\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\{calltime.strftime('%d')}-{calltime.strftime('%m')}.log"
            super().emit(record)

# init the logger
handler_error = HandlerCheckBefore(f"\\\\remote\\Path\\{calltime.year}\\{calltime.strftime('%m')}\\error.log", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
handler_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
handler_error.setFormatter(fmt)
log.addHandler(handler_error)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is indeed to create a custom Handler for this. You can either check before each write that the directory is still there, or you could attempt to write the log and handle the resulting error in `handleError` which all loggers call when an exception occurs during `emit()`. I recommend the former. The code below shows how both could be implemented:

```
import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


class GrzegorzRotatingFileHandlerCheckBefore(RotatingFileHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(self.baseFilename)): # put appropriate check here
            super().emit(record)
        else:
            logging.getLogger('offline').error('Cannot access the remote directory. Are you connected to the internet and the VPN?')


class GrzegorzRotatingFileHandlerHandleError(RotatingFileHandler):
    def handleError(self, record):
        logging.getLogger('offline').error('Something went wrong when writing log. Probably remote dir is not accessible')
        super().handleError(record)


log = logging.getLogger('general')
log.addHandler(GrzegorzRotatingFileHandlerCheckBefore('check.log'))
log.addHandler(GrzegorzRotatingFileHandlerHandleError('handle.log'))

offline_logger = logging.getLogger('offline')
offline_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('offline.log'))

log.error('test logging')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am currently working this out, had to modify it to my needs, but as soon as I am done, will upload it. Thanks, will soon accept your suggestion as a solution :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need whole record to be passed to either local or remote file. Your code emits log to remote if it is accessible, and if not - it logs single error to local and the original log record is lost. I have tried doing the code, but I think I failed so far - I updated the original post above.

Comment: @GrzegorzG. The original record is not lost, it is passed into `def handleError(self, record)` as `record` parameter. You can do with it whatever you want. I gave you the code to write an error, and it is easy to change it to something that logs the original instead. And also in the check-before method, the original record is available as `record` parameter.